# Attaching image of real object to other one

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photo-editing

It might be a little bit scrappy , and this is not my area, but i really need to find a good solution .

There is this little device we have,that we want to take pictures of, and attach them to  many images (and videos?) .

So the device is a little square, 6x6cm, and it needs to appear on objects like windows,doors,bed , etc .

So ,lets assume i can take very high quality images of this device, then to attach it to other images:

1. Should i use Photoshop for this? (i need the easiest one,Illustrator i know well)
2. Should i take photos of it on **green** back and then replace it with an image ? i could see it never looks good enough) or should i cut it into a `png` ?
3. What you do when the object that i need to attach it to, is at some angle? do i have to take photos of my object at the exact angle of the object photo i like to attach it to ?
4. Can this be done with video- in a simple way-without having a pro graphic designer?
5. Is there some automatic tool that do that for you (like setting the right proportions,shadows,etc)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1) Photoshop is your best bet (or a similar raster-based app, like GIMP)

2) Take the photo with a solid background, white being easiest to work with. Any type of pattern/noise in the background will make it much more difficult to get a clean outline of the product.

3) If you can possibly take the photo at the angle of the object you're attaching it to, that would make it easier and look more realistic (as if the image were already on the object in real life). It may also minimize any distortion you'd get when trying to get the right perspective to make it look realistic. This is not required though.

4) I'm not sure if you're asking if this can be done simply from watching a tutorial video or if it can be done with video vs. a static image. I'd say the former is possible (although I'd still recommend a pro designer to do it right) and for the latter, I'd definitely recommend a professional for best results.

5) There is probably software out there that will outline images for you automatically, but not sure the quality will be what you need for professional results.

Comment: Great answer! Definitely agree with the 2nd point, the more angles you can capture from the object in 'real life', the easier it will be to then place it in a way that looks natural. In my experience, manually cutting the images will give you the best possible result. It's not super easy, but it's definitely something you can learn and get good at fairly quickly. The main asset you will need is time and patience to make the cuts perfect (I recommend using masks - they are way easier to correct than selections or erasing of elements).

Comment: Yes, that's a great point about layer masks... much more forgiving and easier to make corrections without losing data. Thanks for adding that!